# How to rsync files matched by .hgignore between two hg repositories

Tags: mercurial, rsync, binaries

How would you rsync files that are not tracked by mercurial between two repositories?

My `.hgignore` looks like this:

```
 
syntax: glob

*.mat
*.pdf
*.asv
*.bz
*.tar
*.zip
*.7zip
*.rar
*.gz
*.wmv
*.png
*.jpg
*.jpeg
*.bmp
*.tif
*.tiff
*.gif
*.avi
*.mpg
*.node
*.ncb
*.pdb
*.ele
*.hh
*.html
*.htm
*.xsl
*.log
*.o
*.ilk
*.cvs*
*.vproj
*.proj*
*.mex*
*.sln
*.run
*.make
Makefile
*.ignore_dirs
*.d
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can produce a list of *ignored* files that exist in the repository with `hg st -ni`.  *nonversioned* files with `hg st -nu`.